# titleLabel.text vs currentTitle in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am trying to make a simple calculator with Swift. I want to get the "text" on the buttons I created. The instructor in the tutorial is using a property:

```
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle
}
```

The question is, if I did this:

```
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.titleLabel.text
}
```

What's the difference? Will they yield the same results?
If so, how does one know when to use which?

Comment: Ignore the optional stuff (!/?) for now, I just want to know what's the main difference of the two methods. And under which circumstances to use which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`titleLabel.text` is mainly using to configure the text of the button(for each state)

`currentTitle` is read only. This is mainly using  to get the title that is currently displayed.

You can't set this property because this set automatically whenever the button state changes. You can use `currentTitle` to get the title string associated with the button instead of using `titleLabel.text` because `currentTitle` property is set automatically whenever the button state changes.

Comment: Thanks. So basically I'd prefer using currentTitle over titleLabel.text if I just want the text, regardless the state of the button?

Comment: Exactly! regarding what I understood.

Answer (score 0):

For `sender.currentTitle`:

> The current title that is displayed on the button. (read-only)
>
> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> var currentTitle: String? { get }
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The value for this property is set automatically whenever the button
>   state changes. For states that do not have a custom title string
>   associated with them, this method returns the title that is currently
>   displayed, which is typically the one associated with the
>   UIControlStateNormal state. The value may be nil.

For `sender.titleLabel.text`:

> A view that displays the value of the currentTitle property for a
>   button. (read-only)
>
> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> var titleLabel: UILabel? { get }
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Although this property is read-only, its own properties are
>   read/write. Use these properties primarily to configure the text of
>   the button. For example:
>
> ```
> let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
> button.titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
> button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
> ```
>
> Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color.
>   Instead, use the setTitleColor:forState: and
>   setTitleShadowColor:forState: methods of this class to make those
>   changes.
>
> The titleLabel property returns a value even if the button has not
>   been displayed yet. The value of the property is nil for system
>   buttons.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/currentTitle).

In simple word:

```
sender.titleLabel?.text = "NewTitle"  //this will work
sender.currentTitle = "newTitle"      //this will give you an error because it is read only property.
```

And:

```
let digit = sender.currentTitle
let digit = sender.titleLabel!.text
```

This both will work because you are reading button's property and assigning it to `digit` instance.

Comment: add the conclusion instead of just copying documentation

Comment: I think it is enough to understand for him.@JulianKról

Comment: maybe yes, maybe not. He had access to the docs so I think for him and others might be nice to include some clear, concise summary which simply answers the questions he put. That is my advice

Answer (score 0):

Both `.currentTitle` and `titleLabel.text` return same value,
but `.currentTitle` is read-only, you can't modify his value (and it's only available in iOS 8+). `.titleLabel` is available since iOS 3+ and you can modify `text`, `font`, etc.

Comment: you can modify but changing `text` will not make any visible effect

Answer (score 0):

```
let btn: UIButton = UIButton()
btn.setTitle("123", for: .normal) //Title visible in UI
print(btn.titleLabel?.text) //Optional("123") 
print(btn.currentTitle) //Optional("123")
btn.setTitle("", for: .normal) //Title invisible in UI
print(btn.titleLabel?.text) //Optional("123")
print(btn.currentTitle) //Optional("")
```

If you want to get the correct title for operations such as copying in UITableViewCell, it's best to use **currentTitle**!