# IOS/swift currentTitle return nil

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

When I use `titlelabel.text`, it can print my results normally, but when I use `currenttitle`, it returns nil. I checked the document. `currenttitle` and `titlelabel.text` are quick access methods, but why do I get different results

```swift
@IBAction func numBtnPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
  print(sender.titleLabel?.text)
  print(sender.currentTitle)
}
```

The screenshot of the problem is as follows

[image]

Comment: You might find the answer here.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134890/titlelabel-text-vs-currenttitle-in-swift

Comment: thank you but I only see that currenttitle is read-only, but that doesn't explain why they show different results

Comment: Is your button highlighted?  it may be nil, see the detail apple discussion https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624032-currenttitle

Comment: yeah~ my button style is pain ! when i change it to default it works!the same reason in pain mode，title text position is not work ,i change to  default it works! thank you very much It helped me a lot

Answer (score 7):

Thanks everyone, I solved the problem，my button style is pain! When I change it to default it works! The same reason in pain mode，title text position is not working. I changed it to default, now it works!

Comment: thanks for providing this information. I'm not sure why it defaults to plain style instead of default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also building a calculator app and I can confirm changing the button style from Plain to Default solves the problem of `sender.currentTitle` returning nil.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building a Quizz app and I can confirm changing the `button style` from Plain to Default solves the problem of `sender.currentTitle` and `sender.titlelabel?.text` returning nil/not Working.

After some search i found this.

```
var res = (sender as AnyObject).currentTitle
```

Comment: print((sender as AnyObject).currentTitle)